# How do I get emacs ERC to highlight the buffer name when my name is mentioned?

Tags: emacs, irc

It used to be that whenever someone mentioned my nick in an IRC channel or I received a query, the name of that ERC buffer would change colors. I think this stopped happening since I upgraded to 24. Is there any way to get it back?

I tried googling, but all I get is plugins for pop-ups or using freedesktop's notify. I just want the buffer name to change color in the modeline.

Comment: This behaviour is still the default in Emacs 24. Have you tested it from `emacs -Q` (which prevents Emacs from loading any configuration files)? If somebody mentions you, does the *channel buffer* properly highlight your nick? (It seems to me that both the channel buffer and the notice in the modeline get the same face: `erc-current-nick-face`). Are you perhaps using a colour theme that either modifies this face or doesn't set it to something useful?

Comment: @Chris You're right. It works with `-Q`. I'm not sure what's causing it though. The channel buffer highlights my name, yes. I tried using the default colorscheme and that doesn't seem to be it. I'll look into my `.emacs` more.